# Understanding Addition Principle

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic

Given from a ala-carte food Menu to choose for

Starter Course = 3 items

Main Course = 6 items

Desert course =3 items (cheesecake or fruit tarts or ice-cream)

**Question**: Find the number of meal that satisfies the following condition:

> One Starter course, one main course and "an optional dessert course"

Can i know what does "an optional" in the question refer to? Thank you.

Comment: While there are $3$ starter options and $6$ main options, there are in fact $4$ dessert options including "no dessert"

Comment: I think the answer is $3\times 6\times4 =72$ expounding on @Henry's idea.

Comment: I wonder if "or" is refer to addition , correct me if i'm wrong
Thanks @Henry for the clarification, i didn't know that we can use "no dessert", too much math and my mind got blockage. So the answer for my own question should be 3+6+4 = 13?

Comment: @ KhoWesley: addition is not the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give this a more mathematical foundation we will use the property of counting independent items.

Just like Rohan said the answer is 72. If you wanted to be able to find the answer to another similar problem just notice you are choosing 1 starter course (from 3 options), 1 main course (from 6 options), 1 desert course (from 4 options). This is,
$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{6}{1}\binom{4}{1} = \frac{3!}{1!2!}\frac{6!}{1!5!}\frac{4!}{1!3!} = 3*6*4 = 72$$